# how to display multiple locations on google maps in my web application

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to display multiple locations on google maps in my web application. How to display this, please suggest me.

Regrds,
Jack

Comment: Following link help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261853/good-way-to-load-multiple-lat-long-points-from-a-database-into-google-map-marker

Answer (score 10):

I'm assuming you mean you want to display the map using the google map v3 api.
You could use this as a starting point.

```
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
​
```

And the javascript as:

```
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xu6nt/ 
For more examples refer to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/

In case you are looking for a jQuery plugin, I would suggest [GMAP3](http://gmap3.net).